# Git get --source information in --format

Tags: git, git-log

I am trying to format my git logs in a very specific format.

I was originally using `git log --format="%H,%an,%ae,%ad,%p"` which would produce the following output (for each commit):

```
b05f827b41856e6f4bcfba20c32f58434ce3a5a6,Kevin Jalbert,kevin.j.jalbert@gmail.com,Fri Sep 7 14:43:16 2012 -0400,206f23d
```

Now I am trying to get the ref (i.e., tag/branch) information for each commit. I am able to view this information using the `git log --source` command and this shows exactly what I want (i.e., the ref which is located after the commit SHA):

```
commit 84deec66f94085ee3a0e6f6204f06296d7a1a903 refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
Author: Kevin Jalbert <kevin.j.jalbert@gmail.com>
Date:   Fri Sep 21 17:02:33 2012 -0400

    commit message

commit f1e1b8d11defc48839557db5e54a5a6f7ffe6cad refs/heads/issue_5
Author: Kevin Jalbert <kevin.j.jalbert@gmail.com>
Date:   Thu Sep 13 15:34:36 2012 -0400

    commit message

commit d7acdbd957d9b477f8849fd5a37882cdd78d8e1f refs/tags/v0.3.0
Author: Kevin Jalbert <kevin.j.jalbert@gmail.com>
Date:   Wed Sep 12 16:48:46 2012 -0400

    commit message
```

What I am trying to do is to include this information at the end of my original `--format="..."` command so I would have output that looks like:

```
 b05f827b41856e6f4bcfba20c32f58434ce3a5a6,Kevin Jalbert,kevin.j.jalbert@gmail.com,Fri Sep 7 14:43:16 2012 -0400,206f23d,refs/remotes/origin/HEAD
```

I cannot seem to find any *format* placeholder that references the branch/tag/ref of a commit based on the `--source` flag. Am I just missing the correct placeholder? Or is there an alternative way to format/display the ref along with the custom information I desire?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Git 2.21 (Q1 2019), the custom userformat "`log --format`" learned `%S` atom that stands for the tip the traversal reached the commit from, i.e. `--source`.
I mentioned it at the time in "[Git log placeholder for branch](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54846615/6309)".

See [commit ad6f028](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad6f028f067673cadadbc2219fcb0bb864300a6c) (11 Jan 2019) by [Issac Trotts (`ijt`)](https://github.com/ijt).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit a562a11](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a562a119833b7202d5c9b9069d1abb40c1f9b59a), 29 Jan 2019)</sup>

> ### [`log`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ad6f028f067673cadadbc2219fcb0bb864300a6c): add %S option (like `--source`) to `log --format`
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Issac Trotts</sup>
>
> Make it possible to write for example
>
> ```
> git log --format="%H,%S"
> ```
>
> where the `%S` at the end is a new placeholder that **prints out the ref (tag/branch)** for each commit.
>
> Using `%d` might seem like an alternative but it only shows the ref for the last commit in the branch.

Example:

```
C:\Users\VonC\git\git>git log --format="%H,%S" origin/maint
53a06cf39b756eddfe4a2a34da93e3d04eb7b728,origin/maint
67af91c47a6672b99e1f742123415f96cbafd19a,origin/maint
a7312d1a28ff3ab0a5a5427b35f01d943103cba8,origin/maint
```

And, using your format (with an additional `%S`) `--format="%H,%an,%ae,%ad,%p,%S"`:

```
C:\Users\VonC\git\git>git log --format="%H,%an,%ae,%ad,%p,%S" origin/maint
53a06cf39b756eddfe4a2a34da93e3d04eb7b728,Johannes Schindelin,johannes.schindelin@gmx.de,Wed Dec 4 23:10:12 2019 +0100,67af91c47a,origin/maint
67af91c47a6672b99e1f742123415f96cbafd19a,Johannes Schindelin,johannes.schindelin@gmx.de,Wed Dec 4 23:09:11 2019 +0100,da72936f54 a7312d1a28,origin/maint
a7312d1a28ff3ab0a5a5427b35f01d943103cba8,Johannes Schindelin,johannes.schindelin@gmx.de,Wed Dec 4 23:07:46 2019 +0100,7fd9fd94fb,origin/maint
```

Answer (score 1):

I was looking for this also. I wasn't able to find a flag as part of `git-log` but the following will work, adding a column to the end of your CSV row:

```
$ git log --no-color --source --oneline --all | while read sha1 srcref subject
> do echo "$(git log -1 --format="%H,%an,%ae,%ad,%p" $sha1),$source"
> done
```

The format of `--oneline` is `%h %<our missing format character> %s` when `--source` is provided, so that gets us part way there. Then feeding the SHA1 back into `git log -1` with the rest of the format specifiers gets us the rest of the way.

Answer (score 0):

`%d` may be what you're looking for - it will show what branches / tags reference each commit.

Comment: %d will show the branch/tag for a commit. Though it will only show it on the most recent commit for a branch/tag. In otherwords, not every commit will have this information only a select few. I am looking more for a consistant way of having the branch/tag regardless of whether or not the commit is when the branch/tag was made or changed.